# Using ROW_NUMBER with Flink SQL

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

I am trying to run the following SQL statement on Flink version 1.10

```
select startAreaID, endAreaID 
from (
select startAreaID, endAreaID, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC ) as row_num
from (
select startAreaID, endAreaID, count(1) as cnt

from
(
select * from Rides
Match_Recognize
(
PARTITION BY taxiId
Order by rideTime
MEASURES
toAreaId(S.lon, S.lat) as startAreaID,
toAreaId(E.lon, E.lat) as endAreaID,
MATCH_ROWTIME() as matchTime
AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
PATTERN (S E) 
DEFINE
S AS S.isStart=True,
E AS E.isStart=False
)) as routes
group by startAreaID,endAreaID, tumble(matchTime, interval '30' minute)
) as wins
)
where row_num <= 10;
```

I get the error **[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: This calc has no useful projection and no filter. It should be removed by CalcRemoveRule.**

I would like help to identify what is wrong with the statement. Is it too complex? Should I register intermediate results as views?

NOTE: The data is read from a Kafka source of rides with the schema

rideId: BIGINT
taxiId: BIGINT
isStart: BOOLEAN
lon: FLOAT
lat: FLOAT
rideTime: TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*
psgCnt: INT

Answer (score 1):

A strange trick solved the problem.

I added the following where clause after the inner select statement names "wins"

```where 1=1````

I found this trick in this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17022